# Can't `beep` without an active tty

Tags: debian, ssh, login, tty, console

I am having this issue, I can't `beep` the Debian10 headless box without a local user logging on a real TTY (ok, meat to be a headless box, though needs a monitor for mentioned test). By `beep`, I mean using the shell command `beep` from debian `beep` pacakge.
I have no issue echoing  `\a` to `/dev/tty1` to get a simple short beep.

The current situation is when I login as non-root user physically from the box, everything work as expected and the device listing looks like below

```
yat-regular-user@wsta:~$ ls -lha  /dev/input/by-path/\
total 0\
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Oct 12 14:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 340 Oct 12 14:01 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 12 14:02 pci-0000:00:02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio-event -    ../event10\
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 12 14:01 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd -    ../event0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 12 14:01 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event -    ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 12 14:01 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event-mouse -    ../event1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 12 14:01 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-mouse -    ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 12 14:01 platform-pcspkr-event-spkr -    ../event7

yat-regular-user@wsta:~$ ls -lnha  /dev/input/ 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 0   0    340 Oct 12 14:01 .
drwxr-xr-x  17 0   0   3.3K Oct 12 14:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 0   0    120 Oct 12 14:01 by-id
drwxr-xr-x   2 0   0    160 Oct 12 14:02 by-path
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 64 Oct 12 14:01 event0
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 65 Oct 12 14:01 event1
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 74 Oct 12 14:02 event10
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 66 Oct 12 14:01 event2
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 67 Oct 12 14:01 event3
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 68 Oct 12 14:01 event4
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 69 Oct 12 14:01 event5
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 70 Oct 12 14:01 event6
crw-rw----+  1 0 105 13, 71 Oct 12 14:01 event7  # < NOTE HERE, the PLUSE sign 
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 72 Oct 12 14:01 event8
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 73 Oct 12 14:02 event9
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 63 Oct 12 14:01 mice
crw-rw----   1 0 105 13, 32 Oct 12 14:01 mouse0
```

also after that, `beep` from ssh also works flawlessly. but if the local user signed out, and the TTY is released to login prompt. `beep` would stop working, that magic `+` sign permission bits also disappears afterwards, and `beep` starts to report

```
beep: Error: Could not open any device
```

Obviously there is a permission issue here. I have no idea. where to look for that "+" sign permission. It feels like the work of InActiveResult/ActiveResult stuff from polkit but I can't find anything related to pcspeaker.
Could anyone shed some light ?

My goal here is to use different beep sounds to indicate errors in cron jobs. Thus requirements like login/active user session is impossible for this job.

Comment: As a workaround or just for a test, can you `beep` as root using the console API? See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1745488/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, thank you for the hint. but I just send the box out for deployment. I will queue this idea for testing when I can log on remotely. I did try `beep -e /dev/tty1` `beep -e /dev/input/event4`, none of them worked, Haven't tested like in the post you mentioned.